# See a list of upvoted questions/answers

Tags: discussion, support, up-votes

I search for issues that I'm facing while coding on StackOverflow and upvote answers that I find useful in solving them. But I would like to see the same question when I face the same problem after few months (should actually remember the fix, but due to coding in different languages - sometimes I would like to check back). What's the way to check all questions and answers that I've upvoted?

Answer (score 39):

If you look at your profile, you'll see a 'Votes cast' tab and in there is an "upvotes" section.

or you could also click on 'X votes cast' in the 'IMPACT' area under the same 'Activity' tab.

I can't see this for you, but I can certainly see it for my own profile.
[image]

Comment: Well yes, and it is what this answer says. Just that... apparently I thought this was an older build not a newer one *and* there's no real difference in mobile and non mobile views on responsive designs - its a function of screen size. So.. this answer is still entirely valid and covers what both your answer and mine was gonna cover. And yes, I posted an answer, realised it was the same thing and self deleted.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek there's no *votes* tab in mobile view. That's what I wanted to clarify.