# Where can I see questions and answers I've upvoted if I have less than 15 reputation?

Tags: support, up-votes

Over the years I've been quite a lurker but I have upvoted several answers or questions that I eventually wanted to find back.

As I'm below 15 reputation, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188141/see-a-list-of-upvoted-questions-answers) does not really apply to me, because in my profile that part is grayed out.

So... is there a way for me to see that list?

Comment: The obvious solution would be posting a good question/answer. 2 votes and you're good.

Comment: You don't even need to write a question/answer at SO as you have 11 rep. Go find two posts that need an edit and once they are approved you will have the 15 rep.

Comment: The message is confusing; no actual vote is recorded if you attempt to vote without the required rep. I've filed a feature request to change the message and make it less confusing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330254/377214

Comment: Did you see your upvote being recorded? I mean, did you see the score change?

Comment: It went up, and then immediately down.

Answer (score 10):

> Over the years I've been quite a lurker but I have upvoted several answers or questions that I eventually wanted to find back.

Sadly, that isn't possible. Your 'votes' were stored as [*anonymous* feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98630/295232), which by definition excludes having a list for them somewhere. The only way to see such a list is to obtain enough reputation (15) for actual vote privileges.

Answer (score 6):

The other answer already answers your question. However, in the question you mention that your motivation is to be able to find the questions and answers again.

In the future, to do this, you could in addition [bookmark the questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/349058) you are interested in. Bookmarking answers is not possible, but you could work around this by either bookmarking the question (and hopefully remembering the answer), or [following the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/349058). Note that following a post would however mean you receive all notifications related to that post.