# How to find votes that were made with under 15 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, voting, data-explorer

I've been using the [LaTeX Stack Exchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for a while to assist my learning of LaTeX. In this time, I have upvoted questions and answers that I found to be helpful. However, these weren't "real" upvotes as my reputation was below 15 at the time.

I have recently gained over 15 reputation on the LaTeX Stack Exchange site and I would like to make my previous votes "real". It would be very helpful if there were some sort of sub-15 rep vote log that recorded which posts I had voted on. This log would allow me to revisit these posts so that I may cast "real" upvotes.

Although a message stated that my vote was "recorded" whenever I cast a sub-15 rep vote, I am unable to find any actual record of them in my profile. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288052/368696) mentions that sub-15 rep votes are stored in a database that can be queried via the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE). I found [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583/did-something-change-in-the-behavior-of-blocking-users-votes-if-they-dont-have#comment971663_259591) showing how to use the SEDE to find the sub-15 rep votes on a particular *post*, but I can't figure out how to find the votes cast by a particular *user*, such as myself.

Is it possible to find a log of the sub-15 rep votes made by my account through SEDE or some other method?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't, as the attempted votes are stored as anonymous feedback, with no record of the user. See [Where can I see questions and answers I've upvoted if I have less than 15 reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352805/where-can-i-see-questions-and-answers-ive-upvoted-if-i-have-less-than-15-reputa)

Comment: I do agree that that error message is rather confusing in that it implies that an actual vote is cast, so I've made a request to change it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330254/make-the-message-shown-to-registered-users-without-enough-reputation-to-vote-les

Comment: For future reference, you can follow or favorite questions you find interesting and wish to "remember" somehow.

Comment: @Luuklag I have bookmarked posts, but only those that I found to be very interesting or useful. There were many posts that I upvoted because I thought they were helpful, but didn't stand out enough to warrant a bookmark.

Comment: I assume that if you'd really want to know this, it should be present in the data dump you get when you submit a GDPR request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request) (but I haven't checked)

Comment: @ErikA Thank you for informing me about the GDPR request. I've just submitted my request and it looks like it'll take a month to process. Hopefully it will contain information on my sub-15 rep votes.

Comment: @ErikA The processing time estimate was extremely incorrect, I received my requested data just a few minutes ago. It doesn't look like it include information on sub-15 rep votes. The only post-related information seems to concern favouriting and above-15 rep votes.